# Piping to findstr's input

Tags: batch-file, pipe, findstr

I have a text file with a list of macro names (one per line). My final goal is to get a print of how many times the macro's name appears in the files of the current directory.

The macro's names are in `C:\temp\macros.txt`.

`type C:\temp\macros.txt` in the command prompt prints the list alright.

Now I want to pipe that output to the standard input of `findstr`.

`type C:\temp\macros.txt | findstr *.ss`
(ss is the file type where I am looking for the macro names).

This does not seem to work, I get no result (very fast, it does not seem to try at all). `findstr <the first row of the macro list> *.ss` does work.

I also tried `findstr *.ss < c:\temp\macros.txt` with no success.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you're confusing a little how `findstr` works. It gets input (to find things in – not the things to look for) either as a file name (pattern) or from stdin, but the things you're looking for are *always* given on the command line as an argument to `findstr`.

```
findstr foo xyz.txt
```

finds the string `foo` in the file `xyz.txt`.

```
type meh.txt | findstr x
```

finds the string `x` in the output of the previous command (in this case the contents of the file `meh.txt` – a nice waste of the `type` command, much akin to common misuse of `cat`).

Since you're after the *counts* instead of the actual lines the macro names appear in, I'd suggest a different approach. This assumes that your file containing the macros lists them one per line:

```
for /f "delims=" %x in (macros.txt) do @(echo %x: & find /c "%x" *.ss)
```

The `for` loop iterates over the contents of your file, line-wise. It then proceeds to print the name you're searching for and executing `find /c` which actually counts matching lines.

Comment: I see! Is there a way to check which parameter can be taken from a pipe? Your last command worked alright, although the output of `find` is very ugly. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can can iterate manually (with `for`) over all `*.ss` files and throw `find /c` at them, parse its output and format it yourself. And well, most of the time it's pretty obvious what a program accepts as pipeline input since that path is usually used for large amounts of data which are otherwise read from a file. I have yet to see a program (PowerShell cmdlets don't count) that accepts arbitrary arguments also from the pipeline.