# Trying to find files with FINDSTR using pattern1 and pattern2 in Windows Command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd, pipe, findstr

I am trying to files in a dir using the command prompt with the line.

```
findstr /m /i "Pattern1" *.txt | findstr /m /i "Pattern2" *.txt
```

The command does return results, but only for Pattern2

Comment: Read help of `Findstr /?` the first findstr will only let pass `filenames` matching Pattern1, the 2nd one ignores the piped input as a file reference is supplied. Better elaborate what you are after.

Comment: I am searching for documents matching both pattern1 and pattern2. I see where the problem would exist with piping the findstr with Parameter "/m" into to another "findstr /m" I would like to search without the pipe and use regex both patterns for one findstr.  example findstr /m /i "pattern1"and"pattern2" *.txt

Comment: [What are the undocumented features of FINDSTR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/62576)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Piping to findstr's input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062100/piping-to-findstrs-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **AND** the patterns parse the results of the first findstr with a `for /f`

```
@Echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in (
  'findstr /m /i "Pattern1" *.txt 2^>Nul'
) do findstr /mi "Pattern2" %%A 1>Nul 2>&1 && Echo %%A matches both Patterns
```

If the two patterns appear in an order on the same line, you could have one regex like

```
findstr /m /i "Pattern1.*Pattern2" *.txt
```

Otherwise findstr regex capabilities are quite limited.

Comment: Your first answer is what I was looking for! You are a God among man LotPings! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for feedback, if an answer solves your question or you find it helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)